# Configuring web-mode for Vue.js (.vue) files

Tags: web-mode

It seems that `web-mode` has supported Vue.js since [May 2017, the "Venora Release"](http://web-mode.org).

Configuring Emacs to handle Vue.js files (extension `.vue`) is as easy as writing

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.vue\\'" . web-mode))
```

in one's `.emacs` file.

But `web-mode` does not like the `<template>` tag. What is the right `.emacs` setup/config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive your configuration is right.  And I think you meant [this issue](https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/issues/1023).  It seems to be solved in Jan 31, 2019.  Hope this helps.